# angular 2 mat select min less than max

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have 2 mat selects in angular 2 one for a min selection and one for max selection. (just few ascending integers). I need to force min < max validation by disabling/greying out options that are invalid. So if user selects 5 in minimum select then all options until 4 must be disabled in the max select. I setup sample in stackblitz. This looks like a simple common pattern but i cannot find any code online. Please advise some creative solution. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-hilite

Comment: you need to post what you've tried.

Comment: @bryan60, sure still toying with it. Will do when done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your template references unique, using `#matSelect` for both may be problematic.

Once unique use this expression on your `maxRankList` options `[disabled]="rank <= minSelect.value"`

```
 <mat-option *ngFor="let rank of maxRankList" [value]="rank" [disabled]="rank <= minSelect.value">
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-hilite-96n7tj?embed=1&file=app/select-overview-example.html

Comment: Thanks. I was on a tangent .. but your answer does it exactly the way I want. I added the opposite condition to the other mat select and it works like a charm.